# David Ogden Stiers, RIP

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Though perhaps best remembered as the stuffy, upper-crust Major Winchester in M<sup>⁎</sup>A<sup>⁎</sup>S<sup>⁎</sup>H, Stiers turned in several roles in the science fiction and fantasy genre.

He was quite good as [Reverend Purdy](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjM4MDcxODE1NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwODI4MTEzMjE@._V1_.jpg) on *The Dead Zone*, narrated and did voiceover work in several anime and sci-fi films (including *THX 1138*), and turned in a sublime guest-starring performance in the ST:TNG episode "[Half a Life](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Half_a_Life_(episode))."

[image]

[Article from Variety](http://variety.com/2018/tv/news/david-ogden-stiers-dead-dies-mash-1202716860/amp/)

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a picture of his role in TNG: Half a Life. One of my favourite episodes.

Comment: @Valorum - thanks.  One of my faves, too.   And perhaps the only one in which I could find the Lwaxanna Troi character appealing.

Comment: Not Winchester! No! :,(

Comment: You left out Cogsworth (the clock) in Disney's animated *Beauty and the Beast*. Seems like a notable thing, and in-genre.

Comment: It seems Lwaxanna was right that he had so much more to live for. He lived 27 more years!

Answer (score 8):

I remember him best as High Counselor Oberoth, leader of the Pegasus Galaxy replicators.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

He had one of the best scenes in any MASH episode. The moment he opened a package from home containing his childhood beanie, he opened the box around my heart. Rest in peace, Major.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It's good to see so many remember Stiers fondly.  I always looked forward to seeing him in most anything.  Though I think my favorite performance of his will always be as the out-of-touch father in the surreal John Cusack comedy "Better Off Dead."***

[image]

***(Or, as I like to refer to it- "The True Documentary of Helbent's High School Years."  Right down the the [psycho paperboy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FsxJfcFVnpo)...)